# How to always display header div on top of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a header div, which i want to see all the time even if i scroll down.

I want it always on the top of the page.

Which code should i add to my CSS file?

Or do i need to add a javascript inside my .php file?

Comment: At least comment something if you votedown!!!

Comment: You were probably voted down because you didn't show any code that you had previously tried, which didn't work, etc. The community likes to see that you gave it the ol' college try first.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the below css to your header div

```
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
```

Comment: Now i cant see my textbox which is just under my header div.

Comment: Then move the content down the same amount as the headers height, how hard can it be!

Comment: Why are you people so polite? :)

Answer (score 0):

if header fixed top 
change:

```
.Your_class{
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the header to the top:

```
.header {
     position: fixed;
}
```

Move the rest of the content below the header:

```
body {
     padding-top: 50px; // Height of your header
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting position to fixed will take the element out of the normal flow of the document and display them on top of (or under) the normal flow. If you want to avoid having other elements hidden under the fixed element you need to use margin or padding in the appropriate places - in this case a top padding on the body element will do the trick.